# Linux Node Module Version Mismatch

Tags: node.js, linux

I am a beginner and I'm trying to run Homebridge on my raspberry pi. When I Go to run it I get an error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ homebridge
/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/mdns/lib/dns_sd.js:35
    throw ex;
    ^

Error: The module '/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/mdns/build/Release/dns_sd_bindings.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or`npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/mdns/lib/dns_sd.js:24:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

Other blog posts indicate this command will fix the issue:

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

Also I also get an error here:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm WARN !invalid#1 No description
npm WARN !invalid#1 No repository field.
npm WARN !invalid#1 No README data
npm WARN !invalid#1 No license field.
```

Can anyone provide any advice? It would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Also versions are $ node -v
v7.8.0
$ npm -v
4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Since the file in question ends in `.node`, it's a binary extension to the node runtime and as such needs to be recompiled to work with your specific version of node.

The first step in solving this would be to ask other users of Homebridge how they solved it.

My next step would be to `cd /usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/mdns` and attempt to rebuild the `mdns` module by invoking `npm rebuild` (as mentioned in the error message.) Note that this assumes you have the required environment for compilation on your Pi (i.e. gcc, g++, make, node-gyp, etc.)

Finally, I'd look into rebuilding the required module by [running a cross-compiler](https://cylonjs.com/blog/2014/11/19/creating-multiplatform-precompiled-binaries-for-node-modules/) for the PI platform.

Another idea would be to downgrade your current `node` installation to the version required by the `electron-rebuild` module.

And the advice you got for installing `electron-rebuild` is questionable since I don't believe you are running in `electron` (I could be wrong.) Anyway, the install is failing because the specified npm command must be invoked in the same directory as the electron `package.json` file.

Further strategies can be found either in the [README](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) or [Bugs](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/453) section of the electron-builder source repo.